# Conditional Access Policy - Service Account Location and App control

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I'm looking to allow certain service accounts that can't use MFA to our office public IP range (which is working fine) and not trying to add in only allowing it to access Power BI.

I've got my first CAP policy that targets all users and enforces MFA but it excludes service accounts.

My second CAP: This works for location blocking but not for app blocking. Can this be done in one CAP or does it need to be broken out into multiple, not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Users - Include: Power BI service Account

Cloud Apps or Actions - Include: All Apps and Exclude: Power BI Service

Conditions - Locations - Include: Any Location and Exclude: name locations of office

Grant - Block Access

Comment: You haven't told us exactly what doesn't work. Does it not block all other cloud apps?

Comment: It will block based on IP but if I block all apps and only allow power bi, then it still allows all apps.

Answer (score 0):

ended up taking two conditional access policies
1st to target user/group and block all apps and exclude the one you want to allow. Grant set to block

2nd target user group and allow the app you want and block all locations and exclude your named locations (public ip of office for exampel).